# Implement FluentSecurity 2.0.0 with Ninject MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject.web.mvc, fluent-security

```
Error activating ISecurityContext using binding from ISecurityContext to SecurityContext.
```

I'm getting the above error with FluentSecurity 2.0.0 when I'm trying to configure it with Ninject.Web.Mvc3 in an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application.

I think the internal IoC of FluentSecurity and the Ninject IoC may be clashing. Or I may be incorrectly setting up the DependencyResolver in the SecurityConfigurator.

I need to set it up with IoC as I need to get the UserRoles through an injected class.

```
public static class SecurityConfig
{
    public static ISecurityConfiguration Configure()
    {
        SecurityConfigurator.Configure(
            configuration =>
                {
                    configuration.ResolveServicesUsing(
                        DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices, 
                        DependencyResolver.Current.GetService);

                    configuration.DefaultPolicyViolationHandlerIs(() => new DefaultPolicyViolationHandler());

                    configuration.GetAuthenticationStatusFrom(
                        () => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);

                    configuration.GetRolesFrom(
                        () =>
                        ((IPersonManager)DependencyResolver
                        .Current
                        .GetService(typeof(IPersonManager)))
                        .GetCurrentUserRoles());

                    configuration.ForAllControllers().DenyAnonymousAccess();
                    configuration.For<AdminController>().RequireAnyRole(Role.Administrator);
                });

        return SecurityConfiguration.Current;
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there another way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same situation. It happened because Ninject throws an exception when cannot resolve a dependency. I solved it implementing my own ISecurityServiceLocator

```
public class FluentSecurityServiceLocator : ISecurityServiceLocator
{
    public static IKernel Kernel { get; set; }

    public object Resolve(Type typeToResolve)
    {
        return Kernel.TryGet(typeToResolve);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> ResolveAll(Type typeToResolve)
    {
        if (!Kernel.GetBindings(typeToResolve).Any())
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
        return Kernel.GetAll(typeToResolve);
    }
}
```

I passed the kernel instance in my ninject configuration class

```
FluentSecurityServiceLocator.Kernel = kernel;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with Ninject but are you sure that `DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices` and `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService` won't throw an exception when FluentSecurity asks for something (like ISecurityContext) that is not registered with Ninject?

In structuremap there is a method called TryGetInstance that won't throw an exception when asking for something that is not registered in the container. You can read more on how FluentSecurity and IoC works here:

https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity/wiki/IoC-container-integration